# How to check if the emaiID exists or not in the dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

am using node js for the lambda function. I need to check whether the emailID exists or not in the dynamo db...If the emailID exists it should prompt to the user that emailid already exists if not it should store the values in the dynamo db ....

EmailID is the sort key
Customername is the primary key

How can i do that ..

Below is my code:

```
var doc = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new doc.DynamoDB()

var tableName = "Testing";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {



var EmailID = event.EmailID; // or any other var which is having emaiID

console.log(event)

 var params = {
            TableName: "Testing",
            Key: { EmailID : "abc@gmail.com",
                   CustomerName : "ABC"},
            AttributeUpdates: {
                verified: {
                    Action: "PUT",
                    Value: true
                }
            }
        };

        // Update the user.
        dynamodb.update(params, function(err, data)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                context.fail(JSON.stringify(err));
                return;
            }
            context.succeed("User successfully updated.");
        });
```

**putItem**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement

   var tableName = "Testing";

    console.log(event.EmailID)

    var parms = {
        TableName : tableName,
       Item : {
            "EmailID" : event.EmailID,
            "CustomerName" : event.CustomerName,
            "PersonName" : event.PersonName,
            "EmailSent" : event.EmailSent,
             "Password" : event.Password
        }
    };
docClient.put(parms, function(err, data)
{
   if (err){
       callback(err)
   }
   else
   {
       callback(null,"Successfully updated data!!!")
   }
})
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this I would use the Put operation and use the "exists" parameter. Setting it to false will make sure the put operation will fail if an item already exists. When there is no match then put will insert the record.

For more details on how to use this operation in javascript please check out the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property

So in your put example you could add the following to your params:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement

    var tableName = "Testing";

    console.log(event.EmailID)

    var parms = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: {
            "EmailID": event.EmailID,
            "CustomerName": event.CustomerName,
            "PersonName": event.PersonName,
            "EmailSent": event.EmailSent,
            "Password": event.Password
        },
        ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(EmailID)"
    };
    docClient.put(parms, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err)
        }
        else {
            callback(null, "Successfully updated data!!!")
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Can u pls help me with code...I tried i couldn't get...am struggling alot

Comment: I added the code in the question....This code will put the data into the db...but i need to check whether the emilID already exists or not...If exists it should prompt the user that emailid already exists....If emailID doesn't exits it should put all the details into the db

Comment: Am getting error Message: "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key CustomerName in the item",  Pls help me